# Is there a unique finitely additive extension of a countably additive product probability measure to the product $\sigma$-algebra for finite products?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider a finite collection of measure spaces $\{(A_i, \mathcal{A}_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ where each $\mathcal{A}_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra on $\prod_{i=1}^N A_i$ generated by the sets of the form $B_1\times\cdots\times B_N$ with $B_i \in \mathcal{A}_i$.

Suppose that for each $i$ we have a *countably additive* probability measure $\tau_i$ on $\mathcal{A}_i$. Let $\tau$ be the measure on $\mathcal{A}$ defined by 
$$\tau(B_1\times\cdots\times B_N) = \tau_1(B_1)\times\cdots\times\tau_N(B_N)$$
when $B_i \in \mathcal{A}_i$ for each $i$.

The measure $\tau$ is countably additive on $\mathcal{A}$, so the Carathéodory extension theorem lets us extend $\tau$ to a countably additive measure (which we will call $\hat{\tau}$) on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. The extension $\hat{\tau}$ is the only *countably additive* extension of $\tau$ and it is a probability measure.

**My question:** Is $\hat{\tau}$ the only *finitely additive* extension of $\tau$ to a probability measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$? What if each $A_i$ is a separable metric space with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

---

**Note**: By probability measure I mean a non-negative, finitely additive set function that assigns $1$ to the whole space. I.e, probability measure does not assume countable additivity.

**Second note**: The answer to the question is yes when each $A_i$ is countable and $\mathcal{A}_i$ is the discrete $\sigma$-algebra. The reason is that we are able to write each set in $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ as a countable union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$: Let $\mu$ be some finitely additive extension of $\tau$ to a probability measure. Since $\mu$ is a probability measure, it is monotone. Then, for any $B \in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$,
$$\mu(B) \geq \sum_{b \in B} \tau(\{b\}) = \hat{\tau}(B)$$
and the same argument shows that $\mu(B^c) \geq \hat{\tau}(B^c)$. Since $\hat\tau$ and $\mu$ are finitely additive and assign probability $1$ to $A$, this implies that $\mu(B) = \hat{\tau}(B)$.

**Third note**: The second note implies that the answer is yes when each $\tau_i$ is a (finite or countable) sum of point masses since we can just ignore all of the other points.

---

**An almost proof that the answer is yes**: In [Finitely Additive Measures](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1952-072-01/S0002-9947-1952-0045194-X/S0002-9947-1952-0045194-X.pdf) by Yosida and Hewitt, Theorem 1.23 says that any non-negative finitely additive measure $\phi$ has a unique decomposition $\phi = \phi_c + \phi_p$ where $\phi_c$ is countably additive and non-negative and $\phi_p$ is purely finitely additive and non-negative. The measure $\phi_p$ being purely finitely additive means (for non-negative measures) that if $\psi$ is any countably additive measure with $0\leq\psi\leq \phi_p$, then $\psi = 0$.

In our situation, we might conjecture that if $\tau'$ is any probability measure extending $\tau$, then $\tau'_c = \hat{\tau}$. This would mean that $\tau'_p(A) = 0$, so $\tau'_p = 0$. The important thing here was that we knew that $\tau'_p \geq 0$.

Comment: Oh, it's a finite product... For infinite products it's certainly not unique.

Comment: Well as a first note, Hahn-Banach should be able to show it's not the only finitely additive signed measure extension.  But maybe requiring that it's a positive measure makes a difference?

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree that it's the positivity that gives this a chance of being true. It's what saves us from Hahn-Banach in the countable case. I also added an almost proof sketch that makes me think that positivity will save the day again.